# How to create database using php shell_exec and sql command line

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a database using shell_exec and mysql commands. I do not want to use php built-in mysql_query because of severals reasons. However, i cant get the below command to execute successful. Anyone can show me some light on what went wrong?

```
$test = shell_exec("mysql -u root -pmypassword create database db_hello;");

var_dump($test);
```

Comment: I'd really like to know what the "several reasons" are

Comment: shell_exec should be disabled, I don't think this is a good idea, I'd never do it.

Comment: @markus-tharkun along with `exec()`, `passthru()` and `system()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
mysql -u [username] -p -e "create database somedb"
```

Or

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password -e "SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables"
```

Reference: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/run-single-mysql-query-command-line/

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('mysql -u [username] -p -e "create database somedb"');
$test = shell_exec($cmd);

var_dump($test);
```

Comment: the command is ok when i run it through mysql command line, however, it i run it through php it does not work

Comment: tried your code in php, it doesnt seems to work. return NULL.

Comment: Thank you all. Decided to use mysql_query instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be the path to mysql in your php script.
For me was : /usr/local/bin/mysqld (osx 10)