# Php shell_exec unable to run mysql commands?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Referencing this post as well([How to create database using php shell_exec and sql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10941124/5718826))

I've followed the accepted answer in that post, but I am curious as to why the shell_exec is unable to run mysql code. It merely returns NULL.

The user already has sudo access, when i copy the following command line into the console log manually it works.

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('sudo mysql -u root -e "create database somedb"');
$test = shell_exec($cmd);

var_dump($test);
```

Edit 1:
Updated [username], if root may cause some issues

Comment: Can you post the command you are trying to run?

Comment: please show us the $cmd

Comment: very likely you will need to use full path in the command

Comment: A better way to create a database would be to use `mysqli` or `pdo` to do so in PHP rather than using `shell_exec`.

Comment: sorry was a formatting issue, the cmd was hidden cause i had it inline with the triple ( ` )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the full path to mysql

Type `whereis mysql` to find it.

It will most likely be `/usr/bin/mysql`

Change your command to:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('sudo /usr/bin/mysql -u [username] -e "create database somedb"');
```

You may need full path to sudo .. same principles will apply.

Comment: tried the suggested command but it didnt work, still returned null,but im sure the path is correct because when i run it in the console directly, it works.